# Building an appointment builder with gui

Tags: user-interface, calendar, save

I'm building an appointment system using netbeans,

i have built a gui and have the functioning code i need to link the items together so that i can use the gui to save new appointments and use the text area to display already saved appointments

also i need to have a search function to search for my appointment title and have it tell me when i have conflicting appointments

if possible can anyone tell me how to get the appointments to save in an iCalendar format ?

```
package GUI;

import appointments.Appointment_Book;
import appointments.appointment;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import controller.controller;


public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {


     //Creates new form GUI

    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {


        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        TitleField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        StartField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        BookEnd = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        AddButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        SearchBar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        SubmitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        itemLoad = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        itemSave = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 204, 255));

        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textArea);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cambria", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Event Title");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cambria", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Book Start (DD,MM,YYYY)");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cambria", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Book End");

        AddButton.setText("Add Event");
        AddButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AddButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cambria", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Display");

        SubmitButton.setText("Display");
        SubmitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SubmitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(AddButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(StartField)
                .addComponent(TitleField)
                .addComponent(BookEnd))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(SearchBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(SubmitButton)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(TitleField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(StartField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(BookEnd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addComponent(AddButton))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 48, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(SearchBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(SubmitButton))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        itemLoad.setText("Load");
        jMenu1.add(itemLoad);

        itemSave.setText("Save");
        jMenu1.add(itemSave);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void AddButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         String startD= this.StartField.getText();
         String[] dateTime=startD.split(",");
         String date=dateTime[0];
         String time=dateTime[1];
         String[] mmddyy=date.split("/");
         String[] hhmm=time.split(":");

         GregorianCalendar start=new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(mmddyy[2]),Integer.parseInt(mmddyy[1]),Integer.parseInt(mmddyy[0]),Integer.parseInt(hhmm[0]),Integer.parseInt(hhmm[1]));
         GregorianCalendar end=new GregorianCalendar();
         String event=this.TitleField.getText();
         appointment a1=new appointment(start,end,event);

         this.apointment.add(a1);
         this.textArea.append("appointments submitted");

    }                                         

    private void SubmitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO




    }                                            


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
  Appointment_Book apointment=new Appointment_Book();
    // Variables declaration                 
    private javax.swing.JButton AddButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField BookEnd;
    private javax.swing.JTextField SearchBar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField StartField;
    private javax.swing.JButton SubmitButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TitleField;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem itemLoad;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem itemSave;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Did you try an internet search on this topic?

Comment: Yes been serching for hours collectively, probably something very small that i've missed or i'm just being stupid